# Hashing a String and related exceptions

Tags: java, exception, md5

I need to compute MD5 hash of a String and googling I found [this](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_md5_hash.xml).

I want to have a reusable utility class responsible of hashing a String, that I would use like this: `AeSimpleMD5.MD5(myString);`.

This call implies I have to check for `NoSuchAlgorithmException` and `UnsupportedEncodingException` everytime I want to hash a String; I have a couple of question about this, I will copy the lines that may throw exeption:

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(str.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, str.length());
```

1) Will the exceptions ever be thrown? How can possibly MD5 algotithm or "iso-8859-1" encoding be missing?

2) I'm wondering what can I do if I happen to catch one of these exceptions; the answer is: probably nothing! So wouldn't make more sense to wrap the exception into a new Runtime exception (probably something like `MD5HashingException`)?

Comment: Just by the way: MD5 has been effectively broken. Unless you must use MD5 to interface with another application, you should consider using a more secure hashing algorithm like SHA-256.

Comment: Not for any practical purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical pattern here is:

```
try {
   /* do whatever */
} catch (ExceptionIDontBelieveIn eidbi) [
   throw new RuntimeException(eidbi); // or subclass thereof
}
```

That's how you express: "In my situation, I am confident that this exception isn't going to happen". If you're sure that the code will never be run in some exotic boot class path that lacks MD5 or ISO-8859-1, this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Most probably not, it seems highly unlikely that `MD5` would be removed from future implementations.
2. I think you have the right idea. There is nothing to do about it, so cathing it and throwing a custom RuntimeException seems like the most sensible thing to do. You don't have to do this more than once though. Just get a reference to the `MessageDigest` during initialization, and save and reuse that later on.

Comment: I was planning to try/catch those lines inside the method MD5(), isn't it the same (speaking in practical terms)?

Comment: @tmh: Yeah, that would be the same thing in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the original design of

```
MessageDigest.getInstance();
```

taking a `String` as a parameter, there is no compile-time checking done to check if the hashing algorithim exists hence the *possibility* that 
`NoSuchAlgorithmException` could be thrown.

However, as `MD5` is a standard algorithim supported by Java this exception should never be thrown.

The same is true for `iso-8859-1` character encoding.

Comment: I knew this, and obviously those exceptions *make* sense. But if their only goal is to signal that *possibility*, I think that they should have been unchecked: it's just like `Integer.parseInt(aString)` may throw `NumberFormatException` (which is unchecked, precisely).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Google Guava where you do not have to deal with Exceptions in this case (because they cannot happend):

```
byte[] hashedBytes = Hashing.md5().hashString(str, Charsets.ISO_8859_1).asBytes();
```